# How do I model inheritance in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, interface

I am attempting to create a game engine that is composed of a few different types:

```
data Camera = Camera ...
data Light = SpotLight ... | DirectionalLight ...
data Object = Monster ... | Player ... | NPC ...
```

However, I'm now trying to implement basic physics for all of these entities. This requires that they each contain  a `pos :: (Double, Double, Double)` and a `velocity :: (Double, Double, Double)`.

In object oriented languages, I would implement it as something like:

```
Camera implements PhysicalObject
```

where `PhysicalObject` contains the two properties `pos` and `velocity`.

My immediate reaction was to place them all in the same type:

```
data Object = Monster ... | Player ... | NPC ... | Camera ...
```

However, I fear that this might make it tough to implement camera-specific functions, light-specific functions, etc. In reality, they have very little else in common other than the fact that they all possess a physical position and velocity in the world.

Is there a simpler way to do this than defining the two properties inside each type constructor?

Comment: You could declare `data Physical a = Physical a Vec3 Vec3` where `type Vec3 = (Double, Double, Double)`, and then work with `Physical Camera`s and so on. But that has problems with composability, as [I've asked about just now](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20921177/445408).

Comment: Why were you using Haskell if you really wanted to do OOP? Seems like that's just trying to fit a square peg into a round hole.

Comment: @EvanZamir Most of the programs I've worked on have been some combination of functional, object-oriented, and other random forms. Nothing's ever been clear cut for me, so it's good to know how to switch between the paradigms in the language of your choice.

Comment: @sdasdadas So what ever happened with this project? Did you end up succeeding with this approach?

Comment: @EvanZamir I got a basic 3D renderer up with lighting/shading and an .obj format loader. (It was on GitHub but I'm not sure where it's gone now...)


It's been awhile, sorry, but I believe I used Chris Taylor's 'Type classes' approach and it seemed to suit my needs. You might be right about fitting the wrong type of peg, but I can't remember it hampering me too much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can think of two approaches - type classes and lenses.

### Type classes

```
class PhysicalObject m where
  position :: m -> (Double, Double, Double)
  velocity :: m -> (Double, Double, Double)
```

You would then make instances for the objects along the following lines

```
data Camera = Camera 
  { cameraPosition :: (Double,Double,Double)
  , cameraVelocity :: (Double,Double,Double)
  }

instance PhysicalObject Camera where
  position       = cameraPosition
  cameraVelocity = cameraVelocity
```

and similarly for your other types. Then any function which doesn't need to know the details of an object can just require its arguments to be instances of `PhysicalObject`, for example:

```
type TimeInterval = Double

newPosition :: PhysicalObject m => TimeInterval -> m -> (Double,Double,Double)
newPosition dt obj = (x + du * dt, y + dv * dt, z + dw * dt)
 where
  (x,y,z) = position obj
  (u,v,w) = velocity obj
```

However, you will struggle to write functions which *modify* your objects using this code - the class tells Haskell how it can access the position and velocity of an object, but not how to modify them.

### Lenses

The other option is to turn to the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1) library. This is a bit of a beast to being with, but it allows you to write some very natural code. First, there's a bit of boilerplate

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens
```

Now define some position and velocity data types. Don't worry about the weird field names prefixed with underscores - we won't be using them.

```
data Pos = Pos { _posX, _posY, _posZ :: Double }
data Vel = Vel { _velX, _velY, _velZ :: Double }

instance Show Pos where show (Pos x y z) = show (x,y,z)
instance Show Vel where show (Vel x y z) = show (x,y,z)
```

Now you use a bit of Template Haskell to derive *lenses* for your data types. This will generate type classes `HasPos` and `HasVel` whose methods allow you to access and modify any value that is an instance of those classes.

```
makeClassy ''Pos
makeClassy ''Vel
```

Now define your camera class, which includes a position and a velocity.

```
data Camera = Camera
  { _cameraPos :: Pos
  , _cameraVel :: Vel } deriving (Show)
```

Another bit of Template Haskell will automatically create functions `cameraPos` and `cameraVel` that allow you to access and modify the position and velocity of your camera.

```
makeLenses ''Camera
```

Finally, declare that your camera is an instance of both the `HasPos` and `HasVel` classes, with a default implementation of their methods.

```
instance HasPos Camera where pos = cameraPos
instance HasVel Camera where vel = cameraVel
```

Now we're ready to do some real work. Let's define an example camera

```
camera = Camera (Pos 0 0 0) (Vel 10 5 0)
```

A function to modify the camera, returning a new one with an updated position, is

```
move :: (HasPos a, HasVel a) => TimeInterval -> a -> a
move dt obj = obj
  & posX +~ dt * obj^.velX
  & posY +~ dt * obj^.velY
  & posZ +~ dt * obj^.velZ
```

Note that this is a completely generic function for moving any object that has a position and velocity - it's not at all specific to the `Camera` type. It also has the advantage of looking a lot like imperative code!

If you now load all this into GHCI, you can see it in action

```
>> camera
Camera {_cameraPos = (0.0,0.0,0.0), _cameraVel = (10.0,5.0,0.0)}
>> move 0.1 camera
Camera {_cameraPos = (1.0,0.5,0.0), _cameraVel = (10.0,5.0,0.0)}
```

Comment: So with both these approaches you need to manually define for each "subclass" like Camera what their velocity and position are?

Answer (score 5):

I would implement it similar to:

```
type Position = (Double, Double, Double)
type Velocity = (Double, Double, Double)

class PhysicalObject a where
    pos :: a -> Position
    velocity :: a -> Velocity

data Camera = Camera
    { camPos :: Position
    , camVel :: Velocity
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance PhysicalObject Camera where
    pos = camPos
    velocity = camVel
```

Then you can do similarly for each type you define that needs `PhysicalObject`.

Comment: So isn't the code duplication a problem now that each instance of PhysicalObject will have a position and verlocity field?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to begin to depend on things like typeclasses and object encodings. The first method is to encode the common interface as a typeclass each type inherits from.

```
class PhysicalObject o where
  pos      :: o -> Vector3
  velocity :: o -> Vector3
```

The second is to build a common object

```
data PhysicalObject = PhysicalObject { poPos :: Vector3, poVelocity :: Vector3 }

data Monster = Monster { monsterPO :: PhysicalObject
                       , ... monsterStuff ...
                       }
```

which could even be used to instantiate the first typeclass

```
instance PhysicalObject PhysicalObject where
  pos      = poPos
  velocity = poVelocity

instance PhysicalObject Monster where
  pos      = pos      . monsterPO
  velocity = velocity . monsterPO
```

Be careful with typeclass encodings like this, though, as too great a use of them often causes ambiguity when reading code. It can be difficult to understand the types and know which instance is being used.